# Error in return type. Why?

Tags: java

Eclipse says

> This method (findClientByPetsName) must return a result of type Client.

I don't understand why and what to do.

```
public class Client{

    private final String name;
    private final Pet pet;

    public Client(String name, Pet pet){
        this.name = name;
        this.pet = pet;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public Pet getPet(){
        return this.pet;
    }
}


public class Clinic {

    /**
    * This class describes Clinic
    */

    private final Client[] clients;

    public Clinic(final int size){
        this.clients = new Client[size];
    }

    public Client findClientByPetsName (final String petsName){
        for(int i=0; i<clients.length; i++) {
            if (clients[i].getPet().getName() == petsName)
                return clients[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must have a default return value after your `for` loop .

Comment: Thanks, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Hey, do not give me your minuses, better help with finance!

Answer (score 5):

Well, your method must always return something (whose type is `Client`), even if the for loop is never executed or the if statement is always false (which it will be, since you are not comparing `String`s properly - use `equals` instead of `==`).

A possible solution :

```
public Client findClientByPetsName (final String petsName){
    for(int i=0; i<clients.length; i++){
        if (clients[i].getPet().getName().equals(petsName))  
            return clients[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Copying code without analyzing is always the best approach. </sarcasm>

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a value also if you don't enter in the if statement.

```
public Client findClientByPetsName (final String petsName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) { 
        if (clients[i].getPet().getName().equals(petsName)) {
             return clients[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Additionally because petsName is a String I replaced the `==` with `.equals`. To do that I supposed that the `getName` method always returns a not null string. Infact the operator == check for that two objects are the same. Instead the method .equals check for the content of the two objects.

---

Another alternative is to throw an `Exception` if the data is not retrieved. Without creating a new Exception type it is possible to use `NoSuchElementException`.

```
public Client findClientByPetsName (final String petsName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) { 
        if (clients[i].getPet().getName().equals(petsName)) {
             return clients[i];
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Pet name: " + petsName + " not found");
}
```

Note: throwing an Exception can be a good practice to remove from the code check like

```
if (element != null) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: You are the second, but anyway thnk you too for the right and quick answer!

Comment: Thanks, you are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

When a method declared to return a value. you have to return a value in any situation that can derive from your implemented logic.

If you can't find a valid value to return you can return a null. preferably, in this case the best practice will be to return  an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) object ( in that way you can prevent NullPointerException from your code/api consumer).